# Combine CASE and IN

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, case, where-clause

I am working with hierarchical data, where Programs (PGM) and Public Schools (PUB) belong to School Districts (DIS). I need to view all the child records of a District, so I'm trying to use a where clause in which I say that the child records' category should be 'DIS', 'PUB', or 'PGM'.

However, the code I've attempted to use here does not work - I get an ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error message as soon as I list multiple values on that first WHEN clause.

How can I re-write this so that it will allow me to select records matching one of multiple possible values?

```
WHERE o.cat IN
    CASE (SELECT CAT from ads_organizations where org_id = :CUR_ORGID)
        WHEN 'DIS' THEN ('DIS', 'PUB', 'PGM')
        WHEN 'PUB' THEN ('PUB')
        WHEN 'PRI' THEN ('PRI')
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean logic.  There is no need for the `case` expression:

```
FROM . . . CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT CAT from ads_organizations where org_id = :CUR_ORGID) ao
WHERE (ao.cat = 'DIS' AND o.cat IN ('DIS', 'PUB', 'PGM')) OR
      (ao.cat = 'PUB' AND o.cat = 'PUB') OR
      (ao.cat = 'PRI' AND o.cat = 'PRI')
```

This, in turn, can probably be simplified to:

```
WHERE (ao.cat = o.cat) OR
      (ao.cat = 'DIS' AND o.cat IN ('PUB', 'PGM')
```

However, that depends on all the values the `cat`s can take

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend boolean logic rather than `case` expressions; it gives more flexibility about the conditions. Also, you could move the logic to the subquery itself, using `exists`.

A rather direct translation of your pseudo-code would be:

```
where exists (
    select 1 
    from ads_organizations ao
    where 
        ao.org_id = :CUR_ORGID
        and (
            (ao.cat in ('PUB', 'PRI') and ao.cat = o.cat)
            or (ao.cat = 'DIS' and o.cat in ('DIS', 'PUB', 'PGM'))
        )
)
```

Possibly, this could also be phrased as:

```
where exists (
    select 1 
    from ads_organizations ao
    where 
        ao.org_id = :CUR_ORGID
        and (
            ao.cat = o.cat
            or (ao.cat = 'DIS' and o.cat in ('PUB', 'PGM'))
        )
)
```